# Interface Builder Lock Item Positions?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

When working with UI items in Interface Builder is there any way to lock an item's position once you are happy with its placement? I only ask as I keep slightly dragging items when selecting them for edits resulting in having to go back and tweak positions.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Select Identity Inspector (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>) and select "All Properties" or "Localizable Properties" in the Lock menu.

Comment: Fantastic, never spotted that, its been bugging me for days.

Answer (score 17):

In Xcode 4.2 it is under "Show the Identity Inspector",
there under Identity -> Lock -> All Properties

See Image:

[image: Show the Identity Inspector - Identity - Lock - All Properties]

every time you try to edit a locked object, Xcode show a lock :-)

PS: under "Show the File inspector" you are able to reset all locks:
[image: Show the File inspector - Reset Locking Controls]

Comment: I just installed Xcode 9 and the project I received had lock for iPhone X. God! you saved my life.

Answer (score 9):

In XCode 4.5 and above, the Lock option is under the Document group.

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is still true in XCode 5, btw

Comment: Still true for Xcode 6.1.1. However, if you (accidentally) drag the view into another view, Xcode allows it to happen, even with all properties locked. It also allows the size to be changed by dragging any of the little squares or by changing the respective properties, after you've dragged it into another view.