# Is there a way to lock the background images in UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface Builder Lock Item Positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268049/interface-builder-lock-item-positions)

Is there a way to lock the background images in `UIViewController`? I have many buttons in front and is moving all the time? Lets say, just like in Adobe Flash.

Comment: Yes, it's answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268049/interface-builder-lock-item-positions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Identity Inspector (<kbd>Cmd-Alt-3</kbd>) there’s a Lock dropdown where you can lock the properties and the view will stop moving.